# How to permute a row in reverse with regards to a shifted matrix

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking at this [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/diagonal-traverse/description/) that asks to diagonally traverse a matrix in a snake pattern (the matrix doesn't have to be square).

First let me confess that I'm being stubborn. I understand that there are different ways to solve this but I really want to make my code work.

I've wrote the following code that travse a matrix **without** the snake pattern:

```
// no snake
public static void zigzag1(int[][] a) {
    int M = a.length;
    int N = a[0].length;
    int skip = (-1) * M;

    for (int i = 0; i < M + N - 1; i++) {
        skip++;

        for (int j = (skip > 0) ? skip : 0; j < N && j <= i; j++) {
            int r = i - j;
            int c = j;

            System.out.print(a[r][c] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The logic is to pretend the columns of the matrix are shifted. For example, we pretend

```
1  2  3 
4  5  6 
7  8  9
```

looks like this:

```
1  x  x
4  2  x
7  5  3
x  8  6
x  x  9
```

Traverse the above imaginary matrix and shift its corresponding coordinates to what it needs to be.

So now all I need to do to add the snake pattern is to reversely traverse the odd rows. But I'm not sure how to easily do that. I can reverse the `(i,j)` coordinates into `(j,i)` for `rows <= min(N,M)`, but not for `rows > min(N,M)`. I'm too tired and my brain isn't functioning correctly. I'm not sure how I can permute the coodinates so that it traverse in reverse order.

Comment: You're right that you'll need two different cases to handle rectangular arrays. The shift direction depends on the rectangle shape. There are probably simpler approaches.

Comment: Are you asking how to create your "pretend" matrix, or how to traverse a row in reverse order? Also, edit your title. As written, it's incomplete. "How to permute a" .. what?

Comment: sorry, title fixed. I'm asking how to permutate a row with regards to the shift I made. That is, I for `i > N` in the "pretend matrix", I need to handle the cases differently rather than just switch `r` and `c`.

Comment: Seems like all you have to do is add rows and shift the columns down. In your example, the second column is shifted down one place, and the third column is shifted down two places. I don't know if that holds for non-square matrices. You might give it a shot.